# Swagger - Add hashtag to url endpoint

Tags: java, rest, swagger

I am using swagger to document a java restful api. This api has two endpoints that only differ in the query string.

```
GET /resources?id=:id
```

and

```
GET /resources?name=:name
```

Since both endpoints share same path and method, swagger ui only shows one endpoint.

I know this not currently supported by swagger. However, I know it can be tricked/solved using the url hastag `#`:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/182#issuecomment-164037595

How do I do to tell swagger that my endpoint can have an optional `#param` assuming that my method is:

```
     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"name"})
     public ResponseEntity findResourcesByName(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name) {
         ....
     }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Ugly workaround would be to duplicate the code in your definition, to have 2 paths : `/resources` and `/resources#param`. But breaks if you have query string parameters... Still looking for an acceptable solution too